# What can I do with the windows files without being able to boot that windows?

Tags: windows-10

I had to force shutdown my laptop during a 1h stuck windows 10 update and now I can't boot and can't repair it.

I couldn't find any useful information regarding windows 10 for hours.

Can I export or retrieve or just import to a fresh install my files/configurations/registry in a similar way as Linux with its `/etc and ~/` folders?

I only have access to the files via Linux or Windows.

I'd like to see what were all the installed apps, get back all the wifi passwords of my user and so on.

Comment: You can start with a bootable USB Key and then see if you can see the files you want, then move them to another drive / USB drive. Files in your Windows user profile will be secured and not easily accessible. You may need a Windows bootable USB so that you can try to take ownership of such files.

Comment: I basically already made an image of the whole disk I can mount on Linux. I gave up repairing windows but I'd like to get back some settings and information to apply them in a fresh installation. That's very easy for Linux since everything is just files, never done for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, if you boot from live discs then you will be able to only get to the files, not touch the registry and many other things.

It will be best if you have any other windows installation in other partition. It will be better to have Windows 7 or Later as secondary OS. Or you can use `dism` to image windows installations.

If you use other Windows installation to recover:

- **Files**: Easy, just you can open the drive of other partition in Explorer or other file managers.
- **Registry and settings**: You can load and edit offline registry. Windows stores copies of registry  in `\Windows\System32\Config`. You can open Command Prompt and run `reg load HKLM\OfflineRegistry <DriveLettterOfOfflineInstall>:\Windows\System32\config\<File>` to load offline registry in specific keys. Or you can also browse `ntuser.dat` to get per-User registry settings. Actually other hives are subkeys of `HKLM` or `HKCU`.
- **Installed Programs**: Browse `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and `Program Files`/`Program Files  (x86)` for some info. You might need to reinstall programs.
- **Saved Wi-Fi passwords**: Look for saved network profiles at `<DriveLetter>:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\{GUID}`.